# How to parse log text file, parse datetimes, and get sum of timedeltas

Tags: python, regex, datetime, timedelta

I tried various methods to open the file and pass it as a whole. But I am unable to do it. Either the output is zero or Empty set.

I have a log file containing data such as :

> ```
> Time Log Nitrogen:
> 5/1/12: 3:39am - 4:43am data file study
>         3:57pm - 5:06pm bg ui, combo boxes
>         7:44pm - 8:50pm bg ui with scaler; slider
>         10:30pm - 12:48am state texts; slider
> 5/2/12: 10:00am - 12:00am discuss with Blanca about the data file
> 5/8/12: 11:00pm - 11:40pm mapMC,
> 5/9/12: 3:05pm - 3:42pm wholeMapMC, subMapMC, AS3 functions reading
>         10:35pm - 1:33am whole view data; scrollpane; 
> 5/10/12: 6:10pm - 8:13pm blue slider
> 5/11/12: 8:45am - 12:10pm purple slider
>          1:30pm - 5:00pm Nitrate bar
>          11:18pm - 12:03am change NitrogenViewBase to static
> 5/12/12: 8:06am - 9:47am correct data and change NitrogenViewBase to static
>          5:45pm - 8:00pm costs bar, embed font
>          9:51pm - 12:31am costs bar
> 5/13/12: 7:45am - 8:45am read the Nitrogen Game doc
> 5/15/12: 2:07am - 5:09am corn
>          2:06pm - 5:11pm hypoxic zone
> 5/16/12: 2:53pm - 5:09pm data re-structure
>          7:00pm - 9:10pm sub sections watershed data
> 5/17/12: 12:30am - 2:32am sub sections sliders
>          10:30am - 11:45am meet with Dr. Lant and Blanca
>          3:09pm - 5:05pm crop yield and sub sections pink bar
>          7:00pm - 7:50pm sub sections nitrate to gulf bar
> 5/18/12: 3:15pm - 3:52pm sub sections slider legend
> 5/27/12: 5:46pm - 7:30pm feedback fixes
> 6/20/12: 2:57pm - 5:00pm Teachers' feedback fixes
>          7:30pm - 8:30pm 
> 6/22/12: 3:40pm - 5:00pm
> 6/25/12: 3:24pm - 5:00pm
> 6/26/12: 11:24am - 12:35pm
> 7/4/12:  1:00pm - 10:00pm research on combobox with dropdown subitem - to no avail
> 7/5/12:  1:30am - 3:00am continue the research
>          9:31am - 12:45pm experiment on the combobox-subitem concept
>          3:45pm - 5:00pm
>          6:23pm - 8:14pm give up
>          8:18pm - 10:00pm zone change
>          11:07pm - 12:00am
> 7/10/12: 11:32am - 12:03pm added BASE_X and BASE_Y to the NitrogenSubView
>          4:15pm - 5:05pm fine-tune the whole view map
>          7:36pm - 8:46pm 
> 7/11/12: 1:38am - 4:42am
> 7/31/12: 11:26am - 1:18pm study photoshop path shape
> 8/1/12:  2:00am - 3:41am collect the coordinates of wetland shapes
>          10:31am - 11:40am restorable wetlands implementation
>          4:00pm - 5:00pm 
> 8/2/12:  12:20am - 4:42am
> 8/10/12: 2:30am - 4:55am sub watersheds color match; wetland color & size change 
> 3/13/13: 6:06pm - 6:32pm Make the numbers in the triangle sliders bigger and bolder; Larger font on "Crop Yield Reduction"
> ```

How to calculate the total time spent by parsing the time log file? I am unable to parse the file as a whole.

I tried :

```
  import re
    import datetime
    
    text="""5/1/12: 3:39am - 4:43am data file study
        3:57pm - 5:06pm bg ui, combo boxes
        7:44pm - 8:50pm bg ui with scaler; slider
        10:30pm - 12:48am state texts; slider
5/2/12: 10:00am - 12:00am discuss with Blanca about the data file
5/8/12: 11:00pm - 11:40pm mapMC,"""
    
    total=re.findall("(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}[ap]m)\s*-\s*(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}[ap]m)",text)
    
    print(sum([datetime.datetime.strptime(t[1],"%I:%M%p")-datetime.datetime.strptime(t[0],"%I:%M%p") for t in total],datetime.timedelta()))
```

Executing this I get the time in negative format. How to work over it?

Comment: Put an `r` in front of the regex pattern, does that find any matches? How will you account for periods crossing midnight? ...I would suggest creating a list of tuples with datetime start/end objects and later checking `if end < start: end += datetime.timedelta(hours=24)`

Comment: @RichieV Couldn't Understand it. I am beginner in Python.

Comment: what is your date format?

Comment: @SebastienD it is mm/dd/yy

Answer (score 2):

To account for time overlapping days, you have to calculate duration for both days separately and add it together.
Please refer below code

```py
import re
from datetime import datetime as dt, timedelta as td
strp=dt.strptime
with open("log.txt","r") as f:
    total=re.findall("(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}[ap]m)\s*-\s*(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}[ap]m)",f.read())
    print(sum([strp(t[1],"%I:%M%p")-strp(t[0],"%I:%M%p") if strp(t[1],"%I:%M%p")>strp(t[0],"%I:%M%p") else (strp("11:59pm","%I:%M%p")-strp(t[0],"%I:%M%p"))+(strp(t[1],"%I:%M%p")-strp("12:00am","%I:%M%p"))+td(minutes=1) for t in total],td()))
```

**Output**

```
4 days, 9:13:00
```

Answer (score 2):

You could parse your log file in a Panda dataframe and then easily make your calculations:

```
import pandas as pd 
import dateparser

x="""5/1/12: 3:39am - 4:43am data file study
            3:57pm - 5:06pm bg ui, combo boxes
            7:44pm - 8:50pm bg ui with scaler; slider
            10:30pm - 12:48am state texts; slider
    5/2/12: 10:00am - 12:00am discuss with Blanca about the data file
    5/8/12: 11:00pm - 11:40pm mapMC,
    5/9/12: 3:05pm - 3:42pm wholeMapMC, subMapMC, AS3 functions reading
            10:35pm - 1:33am whole view data; scrollpane; 
    5/10/12: 6:10pm - 8:13pm blue slider
    5/11/12: 8:45am - 12:10pm purple slider
             1:30pm - 5:00pm Nitrate bar
             11:18pm - 12:03am change NitrogenViewBase to static
    5/12/12: 8:06am - 9:47am correct data and change NitrogenViewBase to static
             5:45pm - 8:00pm costs bar, embed font
             9:51pm - 12:31am costs bar
    5/13/12: 7:45am - 8:45am read the Nitrogen Game doc
    5/15/12: 2:07am - 5:09am corn
             2:06pm - 5:11pm hypoxic zone
    5/16/12: 2:53pm - 5:09pm data re-structure
             7:00pm - 9:10pm sub sections watershed data
    5/17/12: 12:30am - 2:32am sub sections sliders
             10:30am - 11:45am meet with Dr. Lant and Blanca
             3:09pm - 5:05pm crop yield and sub sections pink bar
             7:00pm - 7:50pm sub sections nitrate to gulf bar
    5/18/12: 3:15pm - 3:52pm sub sections slider legend
    5/27/12: 5:46pm - 7:30pm feedback fixes
    6/20/12: 2:57pm - 5:00pm Teachers' feedback fixes
             7:30pm - 8:30pm 
    6/22/12: 3:40pm - 5:00pm
    6/25/12: 3:24pm - 5:00pm
    6/26/12: 11:24am - 12:35pm
    7/4/12:  1:00pm - 10:00pm research on combobox with dropdown subitem - to no avail
    7/5/12:  1:30am - 3:00am continue the research
             9:31am - 12:45pm experiment on the combobox-subitem concept
             3:45pm - 5:00pm
             6:23pm - 8:14pm give up
             8:18pm - 10:00pm zone change
             11:07pm - 12:00am
    7/10/12: 11:32am - 12:03pm added BASE_X and BASE_Y to the NitrogenSubView
             4:15pm - 5:05pm fine-tune the whole view map
             7:36pm - 8:46pm 
    7/11/12: 1:38am - 4:42am
    7/31/12: 11:26am - 1:18pm study photoshop path shape
    8/1/12:  2:00am - 3:41am collect the coordinates of wetland shapes
             10:31am - 11:40am restorable wetlands implementation
             4:00pm - 5:00pm 
    8/2/12:  12:20am - 4:42am
    8/10/12: 2:30am - 4:55am sub watersheds color match; wetland color & size change 
    3/13/13: 6:06pm - 6:32pm Make the numbers in the triangle sliders bigger and bolder; Larger font on "Crop Yield Reduction"
"""



#We will store records there
records = []

#Loop through lines
for line in x.split("\n"):
    
    #Look for a date in line
    match_date = re.search(r'(\d+/\d+/\d+)',line)
    
    if match_date!=None:
        #If a date exists, store it in a variable
        date = match_date.group(1)
    #Extract times
    times =  re.findall("(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}[ap]m)\s*-\s*(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}[ap]m)",line)
    #if there's no valid time in the line, skip it
    if len(times) == 0: continue
    #parse dates
    start = dateparser.parse(date + " " + times[0][0], languages=['en'])
    end = dateparser.parse(date + " " + times[0][1], languages=['en'])
    content =line.split(times[0][1])[-1].strip()
    #Append records
    records.append(dict(date=date, start= start, end = end, content =content))
    
df = pd.DataFrame(records)

#Correct end time if it's lower than start time 
df.loc[df.start>df.end,"end"] = df[df.start>df.end].end + timedelta(days=1)

print("Total spent time :", (df.end - df.start).sum())
```

Output

```
Total spent time : 4 days 09:13:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have two interesting and working solutions from Liju and Sebastien D. Here I propose two new variants that, while similar, have important performance advantages.

The two current solutions approach the problem in this way:

- Solution by `one_pass`, proposed by Liju: takes the regex matches and sums a list created by list comprehension. During that comprehension, it parses the same two strings to datetime three times (to evaluate `>`, to output `if`, or to output `else`).
- Solution by `dateparser`, proposed by Sebastien D: takes each line of text and tries to regex a date out of the line, then tries finds the start/end times from that same line (could be improved to a single regex, but the regex is not this solution's bottleneck). It then uses `dateparser` to combine date and time and also collect the text description. This would be more akin to a full fledged parser, but for the purposes of time tests I removed the description functionality.

The two new solutions are similar:

- Solution by `two_pass`: similar to `one_pass` but in the first pass it just parses the strings to datetime and in the second pass it evaluates `start > end` and sums the correct timedelta. The main advantage is that it only parses dates once, with the downside of having to iterate twice.
- Solution by `pure_pandas`: similar to `dateparser`, but only calls regex once and uses pandas' built-in `to_datetime` for parsing.

If we compare the performance of all these solutions with different text lengths, we can see that `w_dateparser` is by far the least performant solution.

[image: timings]

If we zoom in to compare the other three solutions, we see that `w_pure_pandas` is a little slower than the other solutions for smaller text lengths, but it excels in comparing longer entries by taking advantage of numpy C-implementations (as opposed to list comprehensions used by the other solutions). Secondly, `two_pass` is generally faster than `one_pass`, and increasingly faster for longer texts.

[image: timins without w_dateparser]

The code for `two_pass` and `w_pure_pandas`:

```
def two_pass(text):
    total = re.findall(r"(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}[ap]m)\s*-\s*(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}[ap]m)", text)
    total = [
        (datetime.datetime.strptime(t[0], '%I:%M%p'),
            datetime.datetime.strptime(t[1], '%I:%M%p'))
        for t in total
    ]
    return sum(
        (
            end - start if end > start
            else end - start + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            for start, end in total
        )
        , datetime.timedelta()
    )


def w_pure_pandas(text):
    import pandas as pd
    
    total = re.findall(r"(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}[ap]m)\s*-\s*(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}[ap]m)", text)
    df = pd.DataFrame(total, columns=['start', 'end'])
    for col in df:
        # pandas.to_datetime has issues with date compatibility
        # but since we only care for time deltas,
        # we can just use the default behavior
        df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])
    
    df.loc[df.start > df.end, 'end'] += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    
    return df.diff(axis=1).sum()['end']
```

The full code for all solutions and time testing:

```
import re
import datetime
import timeit
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

text = '''
Time Log Nitrogen:
5/1/12: 3:39am - 4:43am data file study
        3:57pm - 5:06pm bg ui, combo boxes
        7:44pm - 8:50pm bg ui with scaler; slider
        10:30pm - 12:48am state texts; slider
5/2/12: 10:00am - 12:00am discuss with Blanca about the data file
5/8/12: 11:00pm - 11:40pm mapMC,
5/9/12: 3:05pm - 3:42pm wholeMapMC, subMapMC, AS3 functions reading
        10:35pm - 1:33am whole view data; scrollpane; 
5/10/12: 6:10pm - 8:13pm blue slider
5/11/12: 8:45am - 12:10pm purple slider
         1:30pm - 5:00pm Nitrate bar
         11:18pm - 12:03am change NitrogenViewBase to static
5/12/12: 8:06am - 9:47am correct data and change NitrogenViewBase to static
         5:45pm - 8:00pm costs bar, embed font
         9:51pm - 12:31am costs bar
5/13/12: 7:45am - 8:45am read the Nitrogen Game doc
5/15/12: 2:07am - 5:09am corn
         2:06pm - 5:11pm hypoxic zone
5/16/12: 2:53pm - 5:09pm data re-structure
         7:00pm - 9:10pm sub sections watershed data
5/17/12: 12:30am - 2:32am sub sections sliders
         10:30am - 11:45am meet with Dr. Lant and Blanca
         3:09pm - 5:05pm crop yield and sub sections pink bar
         7:00pm - 7:50pm sub sections nitrate to gulf bar
5/18/12: 3:15pm - 3:52pm sub sections slider legend
5/27/12: 5:46pm - 7:30pm feedback fixes
6/20/12: 2:57pm - 5:00pm Teachers' feedback fixes
         7:30pm - 8:30pm 
6/22/12: 3:40pm - 5:00pm
6/25/12: 3:24pm - 5:00pm
6/26/12: 11:24am - 12:35pm
7/4/12:  1:00pm - 10:00pm research on combobox with dropdown subitem - to no avail
7/5/12:  1:30am - 3:00am continue the research
         9:31am - 12:45pm experiment on the combobox-subitem concept
         3:45pm - 5:00pm
         6:23pm - 8:14pm give up
         8:18pm - 10:00pm zone change
         11:07pm - 12:00am
7/10/12: 11:32am - 12:03pm added BASE_X and BASE_Y to the NitrogenSubView
         4:15pm - 5:05pm fine-tune the whole view map
         7:36pm - 8:46pm 
7/11/12: 1:38am - 4:42am
7/31/12: 11:26am - 1:18pm study photoshop path shape
8/1/12:  2:00am - 3:41am collect the coordinates of wetland shapes
         10:31am - 11:40am restorable wetlands implementation
         4:00pm - 5:00pm 
8/2/12:  12:20am - 4:42am
8/10/12: 2:30am - 4:55am sub watersheds color match; wetland color & size change 
    3/13/13: 6:06pm - 6:32pm Make the numbers in the triangle sliders 
bigger and bolder; Larger font on "Crop Yield Reduction"
'''

def one_pass(text):
    total = re.findall(r"(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}[ap]m)\s*-\s*(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}[ap]m)", text)
    return sum(
        [
            datetime.datetime.strptime(t[1], '%I:%M%p')
            - datetime.datetime.strptime(t[0], '%I:%M%p')
            if datetime.datetime.strptime(t[1], '%I:%M%p') >
                datetime.datetime.strptime(t[0], '%I:%M%p')
            else
            datetime.datetime.strptime('11:59pm', '%I:%M%p')
            - datetime.datetime.strptime(t[0], '%I:%M%p')
            + datetime.datetime.strptime(t[1], '%I:%M%p')
            - datetime.datetime.strptime('12:00am', '%I:%M%p')
            + datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
            for t in total
        ]
        , start=datetime.timedelta()
    )


def w_dateparser(text):
    import pandas as pd
    import dateparser
    
    #We will store records there
    records = []
    #Loop through lines
    # t0 = t1 = t2 = 0
    for line in text.split("\n"):
        #Look for a date in line
        # t0 = time() - t0
        match_date = re.search(r'(\d+/\d+/\d+)',line)
        if match_date!=None:
            #If a date exists, store it in a variable
            date = match_date.group(1)
        #Extract times
        times =  re.findall("(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}[ap]m)\s*-\s*(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}[ap]m)",line)
        # t0 = time() - t0
        #if there's no valid time in the line, skip it
        if len(times) == 0: continue
        # t1 = time() - t1
        #parse dates
        start = dateparser.parse(date + " " + times[0][0], languages=['en'])
        end = dateparser.parse(date + " " + times[0][1], languages=['en'])
        # content = line.split(times[0][1])[-1].strip()
        # t1 = time() - t1
        #Append records
        # records.append(dict(date=date, start= start, end = end, content =content))
        records.append(dict(date=date, start= start, end = end))
        
    # t2 = time() - t2
    df = pd.DataFrame(records)
    # print(df)
    #Correct end time if it's lower than start time 
    df.loc[df.start>df.end,"end"] = df[df.start>df.end].end + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    # t2 = time() - t2
    # print(t0, t1, t2)
    return (df.end - df.start).sum()


def two_pass(text):
    total = re.findall(r"(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}[ap]m)\s*-\s*(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}[ap]m)", text)
    total = [
        (datetime.datetime.strptime(t[0], '%I:%M%p'),
            datetime.datetime.strptime(t[1], '%I:%M%p'))
        for t in total
    ]
    return sum(
        (
            end - start if end > start
            else end - start + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            for start, end in total
        )
        , datetime.timedelta()
    )


def w_pure_pandas(text):
    import pandas as pd
    
    total = re.findall(r"(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}[ap]m)\s*-\s*(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}[ap]m)", text)
    df = pd.DataFrame(total, columns=['start', 'end'])
    for col in df:
        # pandas.to_datetime has issues with date compatibility
        # but since we only care for time deltas,
        # we can just use the default behavior
        df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])
    
    df.loc[df.start > df.end, 'end'] += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    
    return df.diff(axis=1).sum()['end']

timings = {}
for l in [1, 5, 10, 50, 100]:
    text_long = text * l
    n = 2
    timings[l] = {}
    for func in ['two_pass', 'one_pass', 'w_pure_pandas', 'w_dateparser']:
        t = timeit.timeit(f"{func}(text_long)", number=n, globals=globals()) / n
        timings[l][func] = t

timings = pd.DataFrame(timings).T
timings.info()
print(timings)

timings.plot()
plt.xlabel('multiplier for lines of text')
plt.ylabel('runtime (s)')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
plt.close('all')

timings[['two_pass', 'one_pass', 'w_pure_pandas']].plot()
plt.xlabel('multiplier for lines of text')
plt.ylabel('runtime (s)')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
plt.close('all')
```